# Is it possible to have a negative, not multiple of 4 offset in a load/store instruction?

Tags: assembly, mips32

During an exam of MIPSx32 Assembly, I found this instruction:

```
Lw $8, -2($4)
```

My question is if that instruction is correct or not. If it is correct, can anyone tell me why?

Comment: It **is** correct. Indeed, there is no reason not to have negative offsets. The 16 bit range is sufficient and the actual address computation is in no way more complex when adding a negative number. And it frequently simplifies code (for instance to access a[i-1] if &a[i] is in a register, or if you need to address data in the stack with the frame pointer).

Comment: Hello Alain, thanks for the answer. As far as I know, is that with a negative offset I can access a[i - 1], but I don't understand why the not multiple of 4 offset, because for what I know i move 4 by 4.

Comment: If a[] is a char array, you do not want the offset to be a multiple of 4.

Comment: @AlainMerigot: `lw` and `lb` are separate instructions.  It would be somewhat reasonable for `lw` to scale its immediate, so the `lb` argument is just a design choice.  But +-32kiB vs. +- 128kiB offsets are very rarely going to make a difference between needing an extra instruction or not, and making address calculation identical for all load/store instructions simplifies the hardware even more.  Plus, maybe you have an odd address in a register and want to access a nearby aligned word. (Is there some ISA that requires both reg and immediate to be aligned? It seems modern MIPS at least doesn't

Comment: Although with a linker-aware compiler, different static data could more likely share one `lui` with a +-128kiB vs +-32kiB "data segment", so there's an argument for scaling `lui` if you can be smart about optimizing based on variables being in the same chunk of memory, or simply near each other.  (If you access much static data at all.)

Comment: You are right. Having a different scaling based on the type could be done. But the drawbacks (when accessing fields of a struct with different alignments) are larger than the gain (increasing the offset range). The former happens relatively frequently, while the 16 bit range is generally largely sufficient. The only exception is when using $gp as base register for static data, but it is not so common to need such a large offset and there is a simple workaround. As usual, better to make the common case fast!

Comment: @AlainMerigot: when would you have a `struct` starting at an odd address but containing aligned words?  Seems to me you'd only have this problem if you had a pointer to a `char` or `short` somewhere inside a struct and wanted to get from that to other members.  Assuming a normal C ABI where the `alignof(struct) = max(alignof(struct members))` the whole struct has correct absolute alignment, and every alignment-required member has the right alignment relative to start of the struct.  So there's never a problem using a pointer to the start of the struct.

Comment: This is true and when I realized that, it was too late to edit my comment and to give precisions. It cannot happen if using a pointer to the struct. But it can happen if using a pointer to one of its field. A compiler could store in a register a pointer to a field of the struct for some reason and it would not be possible to access other fields with an offset from this address if their alignment is different. Probably an  unlikely situation, except if the compiler is short on registers and has to drop the original pointer to the struct.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is if that instruction is correct or not. If it is correct, can anyone tell me why?

I just looked up the manual of an R4400 CPU, a real MIPS CPU:

The instruction 0x8C88FFFE means: `lw $8,-2($4)` (and not `lw $8,-8($4)` as other CPU types would interpret the constant `-2` in word operations).

So at least the instruction exists.

Next thing the manual says is that it is not allowed to access unaligned memory. This means that `($x)+a` must be a multiple of 4 in the instruction `lw $y,a($x)`.

In other words: If `($4)=0x1002`, then `lw $8,-2($4)` will access the address 0x1000 which is a multiple of 4. No problem.

However, `lw $8,4($4)` would access the address 0x1006 in this case. And 0x1006 is not a multiple of 4. This will be problem although the offset is a multiple of 4.